# Export tables as .xlsx format in vue 3

Tags: javascript, excel, export, vuejs3

I have tried to find a library that is used to export an HTML table to .xlsx format in Vue 3. But The libraries don't work properly for Vue 3.

**npm install -save vue3-xlsx**
I have used it but it imports components from ../../dist/vue3-xlsx.cjs.prod.js

```
import { XlsxRead, XlsxTable, XlsxSheets, XlsxJson, XlsxWorkbook, XlsxSheet, XlsxDownload } from "../../dist/vue3-xlsx.cjs.prod.js";
```

and it create module not found error.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue3-xlsx

any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try do the import like this instead: `import { XlsxWorkbook, XlsxSheet, XlsxDownload } from 'vue3-xlsx'`

Answer (score 0):

I have same error, and import like this:

```
import { XlsxTable, XlsxSheets, XlsxJson, XlsxWorkbook, XlsxSheet, XlsxDownload } from '../../node_modules/vue3-xlsx'
```

The `../../node_modules` depend on your file location.

P/s: I already tried

```
import { XlsxTable, XlsxSheets, XlsxJson, XlsxWorkbook, XlsxSheet, XlsxDownload } from '@/node_modules/vue3-xlsx'
```

but not work